# Attribute in a Class immediately runs at the wrong time?

Tags: python

I am fairly new to Python and I am learning how classes and methods interact by creating a text-based game. The code runs great, however, my question lies in the Name(object) class. Wherever I put it in the code,  (in the beginning or in the middle as shown below) I will always be prompted with an input. I suspect it may be because of the attribute name_new that prompts raw_input("> "), however, I was wondering if there was a way to prevent or change when the Class Name() is prompted.

```
class Character(object):

    def __init__(self, name, weapon, spec_ability, health):
        self.name = name
        self.weapon = weapon
        self.spec_ability = spec_ability
        self.health = 100


    def special_ability(self):
        special = False
        rand_num = str(random.choice(rdm))

        if '1' in rand_num or '2' in rand_num or '3' in rand_num:
            special = True
            if special:
                print "Your special ability is ready."
                return True

            else:
                return
        else:
            print "Your special ability is not ready."

    def Critical_Chance(self):
        crit = False
        rand_num = str(random.choice(rdm))


        if '1' in rand_num or '2' in rand_num or '3' in rand_num:
            crit = True
            if crit:
                print "Critical hit incoming."
            return True
        else: 
            return

class Warrior(Character):

    def __init__(self, name, weapon, spec_ability, health, armor):
        super(Warrior, self).__init__(name, weapon, spec_ability, health)
        self.armor = armor

class Mage(Character):

    def __init__(self, name, weapon, spec_ability, health, cloak):
        super(Mage, self).__init__(name, weapon, spec_ability, health)
        self.cloak = cloak

class Rogue(Character):

    def __init__(self, name, weapon, spec_ability, health, boots):
        super(Rogue, self).__init__(name, weapon, spec_ability, health)

class Name(object):

    name_new = raw_input("> ")


def start():

    print """\nWelcome to the world of _______. \n
You are a young hero or heroine
in search of the gold that hides within the Mountains of _____.
In order to obtain the gold and treasure that lies within the
mountains, you must battle great monsters and face dangerous 
perils."""

    print "Will you pursue such adventure? Or will you refuse?"

    choice = raw_input("> ")

    if "Yes" in choice or "yes" in choice: 
        Introduction()
    elif "No" in choice or "no" in choice:
        sys.exit()
    else:
        print "You typed: %s. \nPlease try again." % choice
        start()


def Introduction():

    print "Thank you for joining in on this adventure..." 
    print "Well, welcome to your adventure for the gold."
    print "You will encounter dangerouse quests and enemies, but you will be\
rewarded in the end."

    print "Now, what class will you be?\n\
Warrior                 Mage                Rogue"

    char_choice = raw_input("> ")

    verynew_name = Name()
    name_choice = Name.name_new

    if "Warrior" in char_choice or "warrior" in char_choice:
        name_choice = Warrior(name_choice, None, None, None, None)
        print name_choice.name 
        print name_choice.weapon
        print name_choice.spec_ability
        print name_choice.health
        print name_choice.armor 


    elif "Mage" in char_choice or "mage" in char_choice:
        name_choice = Mage(name_choice, None, None, None, None)
        print name_choice.name 
        print name_choice.weapon
        print name_choice.spec_ability
        print name_choice.health
        print name_choice.cloak

    elif "Rogue" in char_choice or "rogue" in char_choice:
        name_choice = Rogue(name_choice, None, None, None, None)
        print name_choice.name 
        print name_choice.weapon
        print name_choice.spec_ability
        print name_choice.health
        print name_choice.boots 

    else:
        print "You must pick a class."
        start()

    print "Our story starts in the town of Larton."
    #super(Larton, self).enter()


start()
```

Comment: Too much code that distracts from your actual question. Please minimize your code to show the actual problem you have.

Comment: You should put the `raw_input` function inside a method of the `Name` class. More likely, you probably don't need a class for that. Since it doesn't do anything, `self.name = raw_input()` is probably sufficient.

Answer (score 2):

When you run your program, the module-level code is executed. This includes your `Name` class.

```
class Name(object):
    name_new = raw_input("> ")
```

This creates the class `Name` and also *executes the code within the class*. Which is why you're prompted to enter a name.

If you want to be able to prompt the user for a name like this

```
verynew_name = Name()
```

you have to change your `Name` class so that `raw_input` is executed when you *instantiate* the class (because that's what `Name()` does, it creates an instance of `Name`):

```
class Name(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.name_new = raw_input("> ")
```

(Note that instead of `name_choice = Name.name_new` you'll have to use `name_choice = verynew_name.name_new`.)

Answer (score 1):

define constructors for your Character class and subclasses that don't take a name as a paramter:
e.g.

class Warrior(Character):

```
def __init__(self, weapon, spec_ability, health, armor):
    super(Warrior, self).__init__(weapon, spec_ability, health)
    self.armor = armor
```

and in character class, you can define self.name to be None by default

You can always assign the name later on in the logic, by using something like

```
character.name = Name.name_new
```

As long as you do that before you actually read the value of name, you will be fine